# How do I determine if a certain term is in an array?

Tags: terms

I am currently running the below wordpress php and it is creating a list for me.

```
$term = get_term_by( 'id', $ptc, $taxonomy );
echo '<li><a href="'. home_url() .'/taxon/'. $pt->slug .'/' .  $term->slug . '">' . $term->name . '</a> </li>';
```

However, I need it to check to see if $term is in_array $product_terms  so I tried:

```
$term = get_term_by( 'id', $ptc, $taxonomy );
                if(in_array($term, $product_terms)){ 
                    echo '<li class="current-cat"><a href="'. home_url() .'/taxon/'. $pt->slug .'/' .  $term->slug . '">' . $term->name . '</a> </li>';
                } else {
                    echo '<li><a href="'. home_url() .'/taxon/'. $pt->slug .'/' .  $term->slug . '">' . $term->name . '</a> </li>';
                }
```

But it still returns none with the extra class even though I know one of them is in the array... Any ideas how to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what kind of type are the values from your `$product_terms` array.

If you have strings there, like term slugs, then you probably want to check if `$term->slug` exists.

If you have objects, then make sure the array is indexed, and not associative. For associative arrays use [`array_key_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) instead.